# Uses for an iPhone 2G that can't connect/sync to iTunes, but charges & works just fine

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have an **iPhone 2G** *(1st generation model)* that works fine except that it does not connect to iTunes. I have tried to fix it but it seems permanently screwed (I'm *not* looking for  a solution to this).

My question is, what can I use this old (jailbroken) iPhone for, given its limitation of not being able to connect/sync with iTunes. Very few apps work on it as it runs iOS 3.1.3.

Can I store and run music and movies on it? Any other creative uses for it?

*PS: I have an iPad and an Android phone as well. This phone is a spare.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's jailbroken, and you are looking to get movies and music to it, then can you scp them onto the device?

So first I would check I could ssh onto the device when it was on the same wireless network as my laptop.  Then (assuming scp works anywhere that ssh does, not sure there) I'd scp files I wanted to watch over (possibly converting them with Handbrake first) and then use iFile (from cydia) to navigate to the file and watch.

If iFile is not available because of the operating system, you might have to work a little harder to put the files into the correct place for the iphone native apps to find them.

Comment: Which native apps will play video on iOS 3.1.3?

Comment: Hmmm... I had assumed (probably incorrectly) that the 'video' app I have on my phone went all the way back - but that is a bit of an assumption - having done a bit more googling it turns out that vlc is also for the next version of the os... hmmm, I'm running out of ideas a little here - suffering a bit with dark wikipedia :(

Comment: The video app does run on 3.1.3 but needs conversion. I don't think there will be an alternative to that given no new apps run on 3.1.3.

Comment: hmm... do you think this might help out with audio at least? Not sure how to focus my answers at the moment...

Comment: Ah... heres an option - I understand http://www.whited00r.com/ lets you put OS5 on... I'd be interested to hear from anyone who'd tried this...

Answer (score 1):

For 10 bucks, install Wi-Fi Sync from Cydia and you might be able to sync it that way.  This happened to my iPhone 2g and I'm still happily using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it to just have fun tweaking it. You could use it as an expensive USB drive, there is a cydia tweak for that. You could sell it and give the money to people who need it. You could use it as an expensive paperweight. You could give it to me.
I hope those are helpful and I wish you luck in finding the best use for it.

Comment: I was looking for ways to get music and movies on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use it as a remote control for [xbmc](http://xbmc.org/), iTunes on your Mac or [Airfoil Speaker](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) connected to your home theater.